# Adding operators to search (>, <, !=, etc) in Angular JS app

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I currently have a basic Angular app that has JSON data in the controller and searches the data entries, returning results.

**search.html**

```
  <body ng-app="mainApp">
        <div id="searchBoxes">
            Global Search: <input type="text" class="field" ng-model="globalSearch.$"><br>
            First Name: <input type="text" class="field" ng-model="globalSearch.firstName"><br>
            Last Name: <input type="text" class="field" ng-model="globalSearch.lastName"><br>
            Age: <input type="text" class="field" ng-model="globalSearch.Age"><br>
            Address: <input type="text" class="field" ng-model="globalSearch.Address"><br>
        </div>

        <div ng-controller="people">
            <ul>
                <h2> Berman and Co. Contacts </h2>
                <li ng-repeat="person in persons | filter:globalSearch"> 
                    {{ 'Name: ' + person.firstName + ' ' + person.lastName + ' | Age: ' + person.Age + ' | Company: ' + person.Company + ' | Address1: ' + person.Address + ' |  Address2: ' + person.City + ', ' + person.State + ' ' + person.Zip  }}
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </body>
```

This updates the people shown in ng-repeat based on the search terms.  I want to be able to do more complex searches though, like `Age > 30` or `Company != "Amazon"`.

This would preferably be through a dropdown between the input and its label that defaults to `=`, but has the option to change to `>, <, !=, &&, ||`, etc.  Is there a way to do this in Angular?

Here is my app.js for reference:

```
var app = angular.module('mainApp', []);

app.controller('people', function($scope) {
    $scope.persons = rolodex.entries;
});

var rolodex = {
    "entries": [
    {
        "firstName": "Don",
        "lastName": "Malbatop",
        "Age": "36",
        "Company": "Amazon",
        "Address": "405 White St",
        "City": "Washington",
        "State": "DC",
        "Zip": "20015"
    },
    {
        "firstName": "Donna",
        "lastName": "Montell",
        "Age": "56",
        "Company": "National Institute of Health (NIH)",
        "Address": "456 L St",
        "City": "Washington",
        "State": "DC",
        "Zip": "20016"
    },
        {
        "firstName": "Rachael",
        "lastName": "Maple",
        "Age": "31",
        "Company": "National Remy Association (NRA)",
        "Address": "4056 K St",
        "City": "Washington",
        "State": "DC",
        "Zip": "20017"
    },
        {
        "firstName": "Tammy",
        "lastName": "Trump",
        "Age": "47",
        "Company": "Logo Inc.",
        "Address": "405 Red St",
        "City": "Washington",
        "State": "DC",
        "Zip": "20015"
    },
        {
        "firstName": "Jon",
        "lastName": "Macon",
        "Age": "37",
        "Company": "Bill Supply",
        "Address": "405 Conneticut Ave",
        "City": "Washington",
        "State": "DC",
        "Zip": "20015"
    },
        {
        "firstName": "Pam",
        "lastName": "Oliver",
        "Age": "32",
        "Company": "Postmates",
        "Address": "405 Yellow St",
        "City": "Washington",
        "State": "DC",
        "Zip": "20015"
    }]}
```

Comment: I made them up so it didn't seem necessary

Comment: What you ask for is not a short snippet, and specifics will vary from codebase to codebase. StackOverflow is not a good place for this question: here, we mostly answer short, technical and to-the-point doubts. Perhaps the best would be to ask a friend, find an example or try to read more general articles until you get to the solution =)

Comment: I'm new to Angular and didn't realize it would be a long answer.  For instance, ng-show turns something comparatively long and complex in jQuery into a 2 minute solution.  If there's no relevant service/library, then I will look into the answer I received, but wouldn't know to do that without asking.

Answer (score 0):

I think you'd have to create a separate controller that compares the selected drop-down-item to items in the new controller. 
Then run a conditional statement of your choice (switch/case, if/else, etc) and if the selected item matches one of the controller items, run that operator. Otherwise, set it as the '=' operator.